# how to create a dynamic function for wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Okay, so I am making a wordpress plugin for a system to allow people to keep track of points for some sort of rewards system. essentially I am making this...southsideonline.com/points. I want to make this as a plugin for others to use. I can make this, but I want it to be the best for user experience. I want the user to click the admin area to add a button field. I'm having trouble adding a button name to my wordpress options array by clicking on a button.

so user clicks this

```
    <p class="ajax">Show Notification</p>
```

here's the ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".ajax").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../wp-content/plugins/plugin-options-starter-kit/textinput.php", 
            success: function(result){
                $(".ajax").after(result);
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the textinput.php file to add the input field which will save a button to my wordpress options array.

```
<?php 
//function to display point fields
    include ("plugin-options-starter-kit.php");
    ?>
    <?php settings_fields('posk_plugin_options'); ?>
    <?php $options = get_option('posk_options');

    $name_check = "";
    while ($options) {
    $increment = 0;
    $tmp_name_check = "txt_" + $increment;
    $option_check = $options[$tmp_name_check];
        if (!$option_check) {
        $name_check = $tmp_name_check;
        break;
        }
    $increment ++;
    }
    ?>
                <!-- Textbox Control -->
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Point Button</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" size="57" name="posk_options[<?php echo $name_check ?>]" value="<?php echo $options[$name_check]; ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
    <?php
?>
```

There is a successful way i have gotten this to work. I can have the user choose how many buttons that want and loop through creating these buttons and save it to the options array, but this isn't the user experience I want. Any advice?  I get an error because I guess I can't call these functions $options[txt_1]; inside of the file in ajax. What's the best way to accomplish this. Again I'm essentially trying to allow these buttons to be added dynamically, so the user can add or delete buttons and names of people to add also.

Comment: google wp ajax, you should use the action hooks for ajax functions or else modify your htaccess to allow uri access to your custom file.